# How can I know the process detail of an google chrome extension on linux

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have started a google chrome app from commandline,

> google-chrome --load-and-launch-app=/path/to/app/

but now I have no idea what pid it is, or how to know if the extension is running? or how to close it?
running on Ubuntu/Linux

Luckily issuing command again restarts the app :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the pid for a running app in Chrome's Task Manager.

You you can use chrome://extensions or the new [Chrome Apps Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-developer-too/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc) to reload, inspect, or enable/disable apps.

Comment: All this is from chrome itself, I want to do the same from external application. i.e. I would like to know the pid of the extension using c code. or in bash script.  -- sorry for late reply, somehow there was no notification to this post :-) --

Comment: I don't know of any way to find that information from outside of Chrome. What are you trying to do? Maybe there's some other way to achieve it.